# c++ linker , how to link the iostream file?

Tags: c++, linker, iostream

I have a file named `main.cpp` which includes `iostream`.

I compiled `main.cpp` and it worked without errors, so my question is: I compiled `main.cpp` and I did not link `iostream` with `main.cpp`, so how could this be possible? Or did the compiler linked the `iostream` automatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The functions in `iostream` are part of the C++ standard library, which you usually don't need to link explicitly.

If you use a compiler that's not strictly a C++ compiler, you sometimes need to add something like `-lstdc++` (at least, I do if I use `gcc` rather than `g++`).

Comment: so g++ always links c++ standard library with files that containt (e.g iostream )without adding the c++ standart library during the linking time ?

Comment: Yes: you don't need to link libc when you compile C either. It'd be unusually painful for the compiler not to link the language runtime automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The iostream library is part of the “compiler”, in the
largest sense of the word, and if you invoke the linker through the C++
compiler driver, (`g++`, `cl`, etc.), it will be automatically included;
IDE's also generally arrange for it to be automatically included.  If
you invoke the linker directly (`ld`, `link`, etc.), then you'll
generally have to specify it explicitly.  The same thing is true if the
compiler driver doesn't understand C++ (the case of `gcc`).